# grep regex match with random middle characters

Tags: regex, grep, fedora

I'm trying to find if a certain 32bit package is installed under Fedora 64bit. The problem is that the 64bit of said package is installed by default.

For example, if I do a `rpm -qa | grep libXrandr` after installing the 32 bit package I get two outputs:

`libXrandr-1.2.99.4-3.fc11.i586`

`libXrandr-1.2.99.4-3.fc11.x86_64`

I need to modify the grep so it'll return strings starting with libXrandr and ending with .i586 so that only `libXrandr-1.2.99.4-3.fc11.i586` will be returned as the output of the search.

I've tried using regular expressions to solve this but for some reason I can't seem to find the valid pattern.

Some of the options I used are `rpm -qa | grep libXrandr[0-9A-Za-z]\.i586` and `rpm -qa | grep libXrandr[0-9A-Za-z]*\.i586`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it after a bit of thinking,

`rpm -qa | grep ^libXrandr.*\.i586$`

This searches for strings beginning with libXrandr and ending with .i586 with however many characters in-between.